# Delphi XE app using Paradox database stores time as 12:11:33 AM

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, bde, paradox

I have a Delphi XE application storing to a Paradox database (BDE) into a Time field as 12:11:33 AM for every record. The date is storing today's date into the date field correctly.

Here's the code:

```
MyDatasourceDateField.AsDateTime := Date;
MyDatasourceTimeField.AsDateTime := Time;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the field definitions in the database?

Comment: Date field type for DateField, and Time field type for TimeField.

Comment: Should the field definitions be different?